# Псевдонимы для зависимых референсов

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Предположим, я создаю проект, создаю в нем класс

```
namespace System
{
    public class String {}
}
```

Подключаю проект к другому проекту, и хочу использовать String.

Для того, чтобы это сделать, я должен в свойствах референса проекта указать Псевдоним, потом в нужном модуле написать

```
extern alias MyProjectAlias;

using Str = MyProjectAlias::System.String;
```

Все, теперь не будет проблем с использованием типа String. Если я хочу использовать свой класс, использую алиас Str.

Но вот проблема начинается там, где я подключаю 2 пакета Nuget, у которых в зависимостях есть классы с одинаковым пространством имен и одинаковыми именами. Для пакетов и их зависимостей я уже не могу указать Псевдонимы таким образом. Как быть?

Comment: Не совсем понял. В скомпилированной dll-ке не просто указаны имена классов с пространствами имен. Каждый класс кроме этого ссылается на dll-ку, и эта ссылка находится в скомпилированном коде.

Comment: В общем случае не должно быть двух сборок с одинаковым полным именем типов.

Comment: @Zergatul, короче, есть некий Nuget пакет. В его зависимостях есть библиотека, в которой есть класс System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat. По "счастливому" стечению обстоятельств в этом же проекте подключен другой пакет, который использует майкрософтовскую либу, в составе которой есть такой класс с тем же неймспейсом

Comment: Вы используете ImageFormat в своем коде и получаете ошибку при компиляции?

Comment: @Zergatul ошибку в режиме разработки. (ну и соответственно при компиляции)

Comment: Все равно не понимаю. Когда я добавляю Nuget, все dll референсы добавляются в проект (вместе с зависимостями), и им можно выставить алиасы.

Comment: @Zergatul, извиняюсь, метки не верно проставил. Проект на net core, там я такой возможности не нашел для нугетовских пакетов